# Why does changing the second instance of an object affect the original?

Tags: python

With my class if i make an instance of it and then create a copy using the equals operator, any changes made to the copy are inherited by the original instance. An example:

```
class Points():
    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
    def __str__(self):
        return "(% s, % s, % s)" % (self.x, self.y, self.z)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "(% s, % s, % s)" % (self.x, self.y, self.z)

Instance1 = Points(1,2,3)
Instance2 = Instance1 
Instance2.x = 3 
print(Instance1)
```

Output:

```
(3, 2, 3)
```

I simply wanted to know why this was happening and if their was anyway to avoid it without using an external variable

I tried using an external variable to save the value that i would change in Instance2 which worked, I also found a post about the same issue happening with lists and how reassigning like this is actually just giving it a new name but this returned an error, which made even less sense to me.

```
class Points():
    def __init__(self,x,y,z):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = z
    def __str__(self):
        return "(% s, % s, % s)" % (self.x, self.y, self.z)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "(% s, % s, % s)" % (self.x, self.y, self.z)

Instance1 = Points(1,2,3)
Instance2 = Points(3,2,3)
Instance2 = Points(Instance1) 
Instance2.x = 3 
print(Instance1)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 13, in <module>
TypeError: Points.__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'y' and 'z'
```

I also found another question which related to mine but they were using lists as well.

Comment: That isn't a second instance. It's the same instance. Assignment never copies.

Comment: `Instance2 = Instance1` creates a second ***reference*** to the same instance

Comment: `Instance2 = Points(Instance1.x, Instance1.y, Instance1.z)`  should work in your second example. Indeed, Points() requires three input arguments, not one.
For more general purposes, see the "This question already has answers here:" link above.